# Controller to accept multiple formData in nest js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nestjs

How to write a controller which accepts two form-data in nest js?

Below is my angular service:

```
public importSchema(file: File, importConfig: PreviewImportConfig): Observable<HttpEvent<SchemaParseResponse>> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('importConfig', new Blob([JSON.stringify(importConfig)], { type: 'application/json' }));
    formData.append('file', file);

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json',
    });
    return this.http.request<SchemaParseResponse>(req);
  }
}
```

Below is the controller to accept the above request:

```
@Post('/import-schema')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('importConfig'))
  previewFile(@UploadedFile() file: any, @Body() importConfig: PreviewImportConfig) {
    console.log("File" + file);
    return this.schemaUploadService.createPreviewImportWarnResponse();
  }
```

But getting **Bad Request**

Below is how the payload looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarywAJpjN6KXywEIYis
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="importConfig"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{"preview":true,"defaults":{"include":false},"typeConfigs":{}}
------WebKitFormBoundarywAJpjN6KXywEIYis
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="TD_USA_Import_2_warning.xsd"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarywAJpjN6KXywEIYis--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `FileFieldsInterceptor` for multiple fields under multiple fields, like so:

```js
  @Post('/import-schema')
  @UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([
    { name: 'importConfig', maxCount: 1 },
    { name: 'file', maxCount: 1 }
  ))
  previewFile(@UploadedFiles() files: any[], @Body() importConfig: PreviewImportConfig) {
    console.log("File" + files);
    return this.schemaUploadService.createPreviewImportWarnResponse();
  }
```

However, if you aren't looking to save the `importConfig` "file" you could just set it to a stringified JSON without the `new Blob` and have it be the request's body, which might be better for your case